# Ansible Haproxy not working when php installed on webserver (error 503 Service Unavailable)

Tags: php, apache, ansible, roles, haproxy

So I've been stuck with this for a couple of hours now and I can't seem to figure this out.

Webservers tasks file

```
---
- name: (APACHE) Install Apache Web server and PHP
  package:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    state: latest
  with_items:
    - apache2
    - ufw
    - php # Removing this package will make it work.
- name: (APACHE) Remove the default Websites
  file:
    path: /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
    state: absent
  notify: reload apache

- name: (APACHE) DEBUG - Allow RSYNC for new super user without SUDO password
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/sudoers
    state: present
    insertafter: '^%sudo'
    line: "{{ ansible_user }} ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/rsync"
  changed_when: false

- name: (APACHE) Copy some template for Web servers
  synchronize:
    src: files/apache_templates/
    dest: /root/
    links: yes
    recursive: yes

- name: (APACHE) DEBUG - Disallow RSYNC for new super user without SUDO password
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/sudoers
    state: absent
    insertafter: '^%sudo'
    line: "{{ ansible_user }} ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/rsync"
  changed_when: false

- name: (APACHE) Copy the Diffie-Hellman parameters
  copy:
    src: dhparams.pem
    dest: /etc/ssl/dhparams.pem
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: 0644

- name: (APACHE) Check enabled modules
  stat:
    path: /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/{{ item }}
  with_items:
    - ssl.load
    - actions.load
    - proxy_fcgi.load
    - env.load
    - rewrite.load
    - headers.load
  register: modules

- name: (APACHE) Enable missing modules
  command: a2enmod {{ item.item }}
  with_items: "{{ modules.results }}"
  notify: restart apache
  when: not item.stat.exists

- name: (APACHE) Open the HTTP port on the firewall
  ufw:
    rule: allow
    port: 80
    proto: tcp
    direction: in
  notify: reload ufw

- name: (APACHE) Open the HTTPS port on the firewall
  ufw:
    rule: allow
    port: 443
    proto: tcp
    direction: in
  notify: reload ufw

- name: (USERSKEL) DEBUG - Allow RSYNC for new super user without SUDO password
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/sudoers
    state: present
    insertafter: '^%sudo'
    line: "{{ ansible_user }} ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/rsync"
  changed_when: false

- name: (USERSKEL) Copy the user's skeleton template for Web servers
  synchronize:
    src: files/user_skel/
    dest: /etc/skel/
    links: yes
    recursive: yes

- name: (USERSKEL) DEBUG - Disallow RSYNC for new super user without SUDO password
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/sudoers
    state: absent
    insertafter: '^%sudo'
    line: "{{ ansible_user }} ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/rsync"
  changed_when: false

- name: Delete default page
  file:
    path: /var/www/html/index.html
    state: absent

- name: Delete html directory
  when: apache_use_repo is defined
  file:
    path: /var/www/html
    state: absent

- name: Copy index.php
  template:
    src: index.php.j2
    dest: /var/www/html/index.php
```

Removing the PHP package will make it work..

Tasks file Haproxy

```
---
- name: Ensure HAProxy is installed.
  package: name=haproxy state=present

- name: Ensure HAProxy is enabled 
  lineinfile:
    dest: /etc/default/haproxy
    regexp: "^ENABLED.+$"
    line: "ENABLED=1"
    state: present
  

- name: Get HAProxy version.
  command: haproxy -v
  register: haproxy_version_result
  changed_when: false
  check_mode: false

- name: Set HAProxy version.
  set_fact:
    haproxy_version: "{{ '1.5' if '1.5.' in haproxy_version_result.stdout else '1.4' }}"

- name: Copy HAProxy configuration in place.
  template:
    src: haproxy.cfg.j2
    dest: /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
    mode: 0644
    validate: haproxy -f %s -c -q
  notify: restart haproxy

- name: Ensure HAProxy is started and enabled on boot.
  service: name=haproxy state=started enabled=yes
```

And the defaults file

```
---
haproxy_socket: /var/lib/haproxy/stats
haproxy_chroot: /var/lib/haproxy
haproxy_user: haproxy
haproxy_group: haproxy

# Frontend settings.
haproxy_frontend_name: 'hafrontend'
haproxy_frontend_bind_address: '*'
haproxy_frontend_port: 80
haproxy_frontend_mode: 'http'

# Backend settings.
haproxy_backend_name: 'habackend'
haproxy_backend_mode: 'http'
haproxy_backend_balance_method: 'roundrobin'
haproxy_backend_httpchk: 'HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:localhost'

# List of backend servers.
haproxy_backend_servers: 
 - name: app1
   address: 10.0.10.21:80
 - name: app2
   address: 10.0.10.22:80

# Extra global vars (see README for example usage).
haproxy_global_vars: []
```

It works without that PHP tag but it only redirects to the first server and never to the second. Someone any ideas how to fix this?

The error it gives is 503 Service Unavailable
No server is available to handle this request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if anyone ever had this problem, but it was a fault in my HAproxy.cfg.js2 file. I have redone the whole role and it worked.